# Adding items to a listbox in a specific format

Tags: c#

I need to build a simple app that sorts data that the user adds to a `listbox` by filling out a `textbox` and clicking an 'Add' `button`. I have most of it down with no problem but 1 thing is giving me trouble. I need the user to enter the data in a specific format:

```
<name>=<age>
```

And the app needs to show an error message if the 'Add' `button` is clicked whilst data with the wrong formatting is in the `textbox`.

Comment: Not sure if a masked input is an option but if so: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Great idea, Abe.  I was going to suggest that or a tooltip, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be by using the MaskedTextBox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

And since your format is not that complicated you could also use a simple check:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isValidFormat())
            MessageBox.Show("Valid Format");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Format");
    }

   bool isValidFormat()
    {
        return (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("<") && textBox1.Text.IndexOf(">=<") > -1 && textBox1.Text.EndsWith(">"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate your item before adding it to the list. For a not very complicated format, you can use regular expressions: before adding data to the list, match the text box contents against a regular expression.

You can check whether your input matches something like "name=age" using a regular expression like this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox.Text, @"^.*?\=.*$"))
   // add item to the list
```